# How to Type Clitic Examples with the gb4e Package

Tags: symbols, forest, linguistics, gb4e, relation-symbols

I was struggling to use clitics in my glosses, as it forces the use of an = sign. I searched for a long time, but every question I was able to find was specific to math. Normally, the use of mathematical symbols is not a problem, as you can just use the $__$ format. However, this does not work withing the forest package, as shown by the example below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex Enclisis \\
\label{EnclisisorLocativeCase1}
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
[PP [DP [NP [N[pahá,tier=word]]] [D[-ø,tier=word]]] [P[=ta,tier=word]]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As David Carlisle says in the comment, there's no need for `\ensuremath` here, and in fact you probably don't want it. You simply need to protect the `=` sign from the `forest` parsing mechanism. And the normal way to do that is to simply enclose the `=ta` (or even just the `=`) in `{..}`.

Also, you shouldn't use `\\` to get a new line in an example like this (as opposed to within a `\gll` line, of course, in which `\\` is a delimiter.)

If you really need a blank line, or you want to put unnumbered material below an example, you should use the `\sn` macro (which stands for 'sin número' = without number).

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex Enclisis
\label{EnclisisorLocativeCase1}
\sn\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
[PP [DP [NP [N[pahá,tier=word]]] [D[-ø,tier=word]]] [P[{=ta},tier=word]]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you have to use the \ensuremath{} command. The following MWE actually works:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex Enclisis \\
\label{EnclisisorLocativeCase1}
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
[PP [DP [NP [N[pahá,tier=word]]] [D[-ø,tier=word]]] [P[\ensuremath{=}ta,tier=word]]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this gives the error `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ́ (U+0301) not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: why `\ensuremath` ? Isn't it enough to simply do `P[{=}ta,tier=word]` ?